# Make sphinx accept invalid C++ signatures

Tags: c++, python-sphinx

I'm trying to solve [this bug report](https://github.com/wbhart/flint2/issues/1017), where the documentation for a C++ library has some signature with ellipsis (... or ??) for places where the developers don't want to dive into the specifics (C++ metaprogramming is way too verbose); for example `Tk_expr Ltuple<T1, ..., Tn>_expr::get<k>() const` or `Fmpz_expr::ternary operation(??, ??) const` should just work.

If the documentation doesn't declare the language domain is C++, sphinx complains. If it does, sphinx complains it's invalid C++... I'm not sure if the information about Gentoo is important there.

Trivial fix : put complete signatures. Unreadable!

How can one use ellipsis?

Comment: "how can one get away with those while still being readable?" it's totally unclear what you mean with this. What are your goals, stated in terms of observable facts? What are you having problems with while implementing?

Comment: It can trivially be fixed by writing the complete signatures, but that's completely unreadable...

Comment: Your default domain seems to be set to C in properties, but you are documenting C++ code. You can try using `cpp:function` instead to override domain. As for the "..." issue I'm not so sure, but maybe also cpp:expr can give similar formatting.

Comment: That can't be a question of invalid domain as the error messages clearly state it's expecting C++ and finding invalid C++. Both ... and ?? are problematic but should be made acceptable in some way...

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx uses Pygments for syntax highlighting, and that's the source of the messages. You must have valid syntax for the language for highlighting to occur. You can either change the language to `text` which will remove desirable highlighting, or you can remove or comment out the elided output.

Comment: Is this really about Pygments? The error messages come from https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/4.x/sphinx/domains/cpp.py and https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/4.x/sphinx/util/cfamily.py